# Combining set builder and summation notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, summation

What's the best notation for the sum of a subset?

Given $S = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$, let's say I want to find the sum of the squares of elements less than 4.

Initially I used the following notation:
$$\sum_{\{i \in S:i<4\}}i^2$$

But I thought there is missing information, since only the set is provided. Here's alternative #1:
$$\sum_{i\in\{x \in S:x<4\}}i^2$$

That seems verbose, so here's alternative #2, with some reordering:
$$\sum\{i^2:i \in S:i <4\}$$

Which of the above is best, and is there an even better notation?

Comment: If you use this sum more than once or twice, you should consider defining $T=\{x\in S:x<4\}$.  Then your sum can be over $i\in T$.  Also, your alternative#2 with the double colons, is highly nonstandard.

Comment: It's only used once in my case, but that is a good idea, thanks.

Comment: Yes, instead of $\{i^2 : i\in S : i< 4\}$, you should write $\{i^2 : i\in S\text{ and }i<4\}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's pretty common to see notation like $$\sum_{\substack{i \in S \\ i < 4}} i^2$$

Here the $i<4$ is a condition you're imposing on the $i$ appearing in the sum (in addition to $i\in S$).

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be the simplest option.